# Connection refused to local ffserver

Tags: video, webserver, ffmpeg

I am unable to send my desktop capture to a localhost `ffserver`: the connection to the local server is refused.

```
# ffserver >/dev/null 2>&1 &
# ffmpeg -video_size 1600x900 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0 \
 -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
....
[tcp @ 0x56514ba629e0] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused
), trying next address
```

I have tried to add the option `ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255` in `/etc/ffserver.conf` without success

**What are the reasons that perclude me from sending my video to http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm**

Answer (score 0):

Try useing these ACL settings:

```
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
```

With this Command:

```
ffserver >/dev/null 2>&1 &
ffmpeg -video_size 1600x900 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0 \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0 http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

It seems as though the connection may be being refused because of the word localhost.